# how to extract web text in android like rss to display it on android GUI?

Tags: android

how to  extract some criteria from this page http://www.zigwheels.com/api/zigtvApi.php?method=data&module=News&section=News

and filter this ( content_id , thumbnail, summary , headline , image) to display them as rss feeds in my android GUI

Answer (score 1):

The output from that URL looks like a JSON feed. You can easily parse JSON data in Android using the `JsonObject` - see [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) tutorial for a comprehensive example.

A better (and probably easier) solution would be to use [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and extract the object that way. I've written a *full* (compilable) program you can use as an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198626/1101070).

Comment: hey there check this this is the simplist    http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/                                                                  ''''''''''''''          but the problem   is with ,,,JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray(“earthquakes”);     ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,     in my case as  this link ,,,,,http://www.zigwheels.com/api/zigtvApi.php?method=data&module=News&section=News,,,,,, it is not array so i will return the object directly so how will it be made  how to loop or to get all info from page ???

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a `JSONArray` from that page. You should create some objects from that `JSONArray` which will be later displayed in a `ListView`. For retrieving objects from that feed you could use `Json` or `Gson` as @Marvin Pinto suggested, or you could also have a look at my [`ObjectFactory`](https://github.com/ovy9086/ObjectFactory) project, which is a very simple and easy to use parser. It can simply create your objects from a json or xml feed, and you could also use it asynchronously.

After you fetch your objects, with your desired option, you can create a `ListAdapter` and use it to display your objects in your `ListView`.

Comment: hey there check this this is the simplist    http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/                                                                  ''''''''''''''          but the problem   is with ,,,JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray(“earthquakes”);     ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,     in my case as  this link ,,,,,http://www.zigwheels.com/api/zigtvApi.php?method=data&module=News&section=News,,,,,, it is not array so i will return the object directly so how will it be made  how to loop or to get all info from page ???