# Converting given string to List<Class> in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a string discounts with value:

```
"[{\"startInterval\":0,\"endInterval\":3,\"discount\":1000.0},
 {\"startInterval\":3,\"endInterval\":6,\"discount\":750.0},
 {\"startInterval\":6,\"endInterval\":9,\"discount\":500.0},
 {\"startInterval\":9,\"endInterval\":12,\"discount\":10.0}]"
```

My Discount class has model:

```
public class Discount  {

    private int startInterval;
    private int endInterval;
    private double discount;

    public Discount() {

    }

    public int getStartInterval() {
        return startInterval;
    }

    public void setStartInterval(int startInterval) {
        this.startInterval = startInterval;
    }

    public int getEndInterval() {
        return endInterval;
    }

    public void setEndInterval(int endInterval) {
        this.endInterval = endInterval;
    }

    public Double getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

}
```

I want to serialize the string to `List<Discount>`. How do I do that? I have tried converting the string to `JSONArray` (gson and json), but I'm getting some errors.

Note that:

```
[{"startInterval":0,"endInterval":3,"discount":1000.0},
 {"startInterval":3,"endInterval":6,"discount":750.0},
 {"startInterval":6,"endInterval":9,"discount":500.0},
 {"startInterval":9,"endInterval":12,"discount":10.0}]
```

is stored in mysql db. I am fetching this into a string discounts, then trying to serialize it.

Comment: Serializing an object with GSON is pretty easy, have you tried [these methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038553/serialize-java-object-with-gson)? And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186806/gson-turn-an-array-of-data-objects-into-json-android) one?

Comment: take a look at [jackson 2](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) JSON to Java Object...

Comment: @Oneiros  These link serialize a single json element. What I need is serializing to List<Class>


List<Discount> rateList = mapper.readValue(disounts,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Discount.class)); 

This is also not helping

Comment: @Plirkee Tried this
List<Discount> dicountList = mapper.readValue(disounts,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().cons‌​tructCollectionType(‌​List.class, Discount.class));

This calls the constructor of Discount class with paramters as disount string.
The string contains the entire array. If it was single element, it could have been serialized

Comment: Look at the second link I provided, a list of objects is used. GSON automatically deals with Java collections. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Oneiros Should work. I am getting an exception: IllegalStateException  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $  

I'm doing

Type type = new TypeToken<List<Discount>>(){}.getType();

List<Discount> inpList = new Gson().fromJson(discounts, type);

where discounts has the value :  

"[{\"startInterval\":0,\"endInterval\":3,\"discount\":1000.0},{\"startInterval\":3,\"endInterval\":6,\"discount\":750.0},{\"startInterval\":6,\"endInterval\":9,\"discount\":500.0},{\"startInterval\":9,\"endInterval\":12,\"discount\":10.0}]"

Comment: @Oneiros Thanks it works now. My bad

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post the full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GSON:

```
String json = /* your json */
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Discount>>().getType();
List<Discount> discounts = new Gson().fromJson(json , type);
```